Title of program about horror and/or SF movies & TV
This question is solved.
Decades ago I saw at least once a movie or program on American TV about horror and/or science fiction movies and/or TV shows.
What I remember specifically is not the body of the movie, program, or documentary, but a scene or clip that I think was shown during the ending credits.
I would love to know which movie or program that scene originally came from, so identifying the program where it was shown during the credits would be a step to finding where it came from.
And seeing an image of that scene would help to make my description of it more precise and help to identify the source.
As far as I remember, the scene was in black and white, set outdoors, with a painted backdrop showing an alien planet with craters and mountains, and beyond the horizon a black sky filled with stars.  In the foreground was a long table with a number of nonhuman people sitting, standing, or whatever behind it.
It has been suggested elsewhere that this could be a clip of the allies of the Daleks from the Dr. Who serial "The Daleks' Master Plan" (13 November 1965 to 29 January 1966), or from the single episode story "Mission to the Unknown" (9 October 1965).
One alien ally seen in "Mission to the Unknown" but not in "The Daleks' Master Plan" is known to fans as "Mr. Christmas Tree" and may have the official character name of Sentreal.  
https://delegatedetective.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/mission-to-find-the-unknown/sentreal-mission/1
He has a very strange abstract look like he might be a plant or a machine.  And if I remember correctly at least one of the aliens from the scene I remember also had a strange abstract look like it might have been a plant or a machine instead of an animal.
Can anyone identify the scene and the program I remember seeing it in and/or the movie or program it came from.

12-28-2017 This review of Evil Brain From Outer Space (1964) says that clips from Evil Brain From Outer Space (1964) are seen in It Came From Hollywood.
http://www.stomptokyo.com/badmoviereport/reviews/E/evilbrain.html2 
The wikipedia article on It Came From Hollywood (1982) says that it includes clips from Evil Brain From Outer Space (1964).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Came_from_Hollywood3
Thus I saw that clip in It Came From Hollywood (1982).

It seems I didn't need to ask this question.  I have found what seems to be the original source of the scene I remember, so it is less important to me to learn what program had the scene in the ending credits. 
I had a hunch that the scene could be from a Japanese movie or TV series, and tried looking up Japanese horror, scifi, and superheo movies.
The Japanese short movie series Supa Jaiantsu had 9 films produced from 1957 to 1959 featuring Super Giant, a hero from outer space, known as starman in english versions.  They were edited into four movies and dubbed into English with the titles Atomic Rulers of the World (1964), Invaders from Space (1965), Attack from Space (1964), and Evil Brain from Outer Space (1964).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Giant1
I found online reviews of Attack from Space (1964) and Atomic Rulers of the World (1964) that include stills of a scene very similar to what I remember. 
http://tarstarkas.net/2004/07/starman-attack-from-space/2
http://commonsensemoviereviews.blogspot.com/2009/05/atomic-rulers-of-world-1964.html3
So it seems that the scene I remember was from the Starman series of films.
12-28-2017 This review of Evil Brain From Outer Space (1964) says that clips from Evil Brain From Outer Space (1964) are seen in It Came From Hollywood.
http://www.stomptokyo.com/badmoviereport/reviews/E/evilbrain.html4 
The wikipedia article on It Came From Hollywood (1982) says that it includes clips from Evil Brain From Outer Space (1964).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Came_from_Hollywood5
Thus I saw that clip in It Came From Hollywood (1982).

You are allowed to answer your own question, so you might as well click to accept the answer.
